# LNK1313 visual studio error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, libraries, managed-c++, libtiff

I am trying to compile and run some code, part that I wrote using visual studio and part of this task requires me to use a library I downloaded. The error message reads "fatal error LNK1313: ijw/native module detected; cannot link with pure modules". I'm guessing that this has to do with the library (libtiff if anyone was wondering which one) being considered a pure module and the visual studio project is not? Is there a way to handle such an error? I have not worked with C++ (Or visual studio) in a while and would appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the module that uses the libtiff library is not set to link with clr:/pure (See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx)

See Project Properties / General / Common Language Runtime support

Comment: Thanks, I've spent way too much time working with Java and web-dev that I forgot most c/c++ environment setup.